# Make "Figure" text bold in quarto figure captions

Tags: markdown, quarto

By default, when producing html, [quarto](https://quarto.org/) adds the caption to a figure to the automatically generated text "Figure NN. ", where NN is the number of the figure. For example: the following R chunk

````
```{r}
#| label: myFirstFigure
#| fig-cap: A caption
plot(1:10)
```
````

Will produce caption which looks like that:

> Figure 1. A caption

However, what I need is a caption which looks like that:

> **Figure 1.** A caption

How can I achieve that?

Edit: @shafee shows in his answer that it is possible to make it '**Figure** 1.', i.e. just the "Figure" in bold, but not the number. However, I would like to have both in bold (including the dot). Scientific journals often use bold for the "Figure", number and the first sentence of the caption.

Answer (score 3):

You can specify the title prefix used for captions using [`*-title`](https://quarto.org/docs/authoring/cross-references.html#titles) options.

````
---
title: "Figure"
format: html
crossref:
  fig-title: '**Figure**'
  fig-labels: arabic
  title-delim: "**.**"
---

## Quarto

```{r}
#| label: fig-myFirstFigure
#| fig-cap: A caption

plot(1:10)
```
````

**One very important detail to note, you must prefix your chunk label name with `fig-` (e.g. `fig-yourChunkLabelName`) to make these options work.**

---

[image: figure caption prefix (partially bold)]

---

Also note that this solution could only bold the figure prefix `Figure` and the prefix separator `.`, but couldn't find a way to bold the numbers.

Comment: "but couldn't find a way to bold the numbers." Unfortunately, that is actually the issue here. I need it in that particular style, with number and title in bold. I was hoping something can be done with css, but until now I have not figured a way.

Comment: If this is a simple html document (I mean not with chapter like section), you can give a try with css counter. Though I haven’t tested yet, using css counter for figure and control the prefix explicitly could be an option of worth trying.

Comment: Well, I have better workarounds in Rmarkdown; one of the major points of using quarto was for me that figure captions and references are done automatically and painlessly.

Comment: For HTML, you can use CSS to bold the figure number or listing number.  For example to bold a listing number, you could add the following to you a styles.css file:

`.listing p{
  font-weight:bold;
}`
 
and then add the following to your YAML: 
`format:
  html:
    number-sections: true
    css: styles.css`

Answer (score 1):

In the meanwhile, I came up with another solution which creates the desired output, at least for HTML and probably not under all circumstances. Basically, I found that creating a lua filter for quarto is not an option, because apparently the filters are run *before* quarto adds the figure numbering. Therefore, it is necessary to run pandoc with a custom lua filter *after* quarto has rendered the output. I found that the following works for me:

```
quarto render test.qmd -t html | pandoc -L ./figfilt.lua -o test.html
```

Here is the file `figfilt.lua`:

```
function Div(a)
  if a.classes[1] ~= "quarto-figure" then return end

  a.content = a.content:walk({
    Plain = function(el) 
      if el.content[1].t == "Str" and 
         string.find(el.content[1].text, "^Figure") then
        el.content[1] = pandoc.Strong(el.content[1])
      end
      return el
    end,
  })

  return a
end
```

As you can see, the images are no longer in an `Image` class if you don't specify the `-f html` option (but if you do, then you lose all the Quarto goodies like javascript). So it is a guesswork, really, and I don't think this solution is the best one.