# How to run a lua filter in Quarto after the crossreferences were added?

Tags: lua, pandoc, quarto

I am trying to write a lua filter which works on figure caption titles, i.e. stuff like "Figure 1" in the figure caption. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74097579/make-figure-text-bold-in-quarto-figure-captions/74392394#74392394) for background. Basically I want to make this "Figure 1" part in bold (including figure number).

However, it appears that when Quarto runs a lua filter the caption of the Image object in AST does not yet contain the figure title; the caption at this stage is `[ Str "Your", Space, Str "Caption" ]`, whereas after Quarto is done (and you convert the output to native, for example) it becomes `[ Str "Figure", Str "\160", Str "1", Str ":", Space, "Your", Space, Str "Caption" ]`.

My question: is there a way of running a lua filter in quarto *after* the cross-references and caption titles have been added?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quarto supports `quarto` as a special specifier in the filter list, which allows to set the position of the default Quarto filters relative to other filters:

```yaml
---
filters:
  - run-me-first.lua
  - quarto
  - my-figure-modifier.lua
---
```